# How to create Calendar subfolders if they do not exist?

Tags: vba

I am trying to make it so that if the subfolder that is being set by arrCal doesn't exist, then the script will create it and rerun.  I tried adding the following

```
On Error Resume Next
    MkDir CalFolder.Folders(arrCal)
    On Error GoTo 0
```

But it is still erroring out because the subfolder doesn't exist.

Looking for any possible solutions.

Thank you in advance!

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub CreateOutlookAppointments()
   Sheets("PTH").Select
    On Error GoTo Err_Execute
     
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim blnCreated As Boolean
    Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim CalFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim subFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim arrCal As String
     
    Dim i As Long
     
    On Error Resume Next
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
     
    If olApp Is Nothing Then
        Set olApp = Outlook.Application
        blnCreated = True
        Err.Clear
    Else
        blnCreated = False
    End If
     
    On Error GoTo 0
     
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set CalFolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    
         
    i = 3
    Do Until Trim(Cells(i, 1).Value) = ""
     If Trim(Cells(i, 12).Value) = "" Then
    Set olAppt = CalFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
    arrCal = Cells(i, 6).Value
    Set subFolder = CalFolder.Folders(arrCal)
    On Error Resume Next
    MkDir CalFolder.Folders(arrCal)
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set olAppt = subFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
    
         
    'MsgBox subFolder, vbOKCancel, "Folder Name"
           
    With olAppt
     
    'Define calendar item properties
        .Start = Cells(i, 5) + TimeValue("9:00:00")
        .End = Cells(i, 5) + TimeValue("17:00:00")
        .Subject = Cells(i, 1) + " " + Cells(i, 2)
        .Body = Cells(i, 6) & vbNewLine & Cells(2, 4) & vbNewLine & Cells(i, 4)
        .ReminderSet = False
        .Save
' For meetings or Group Calendars
     ' .Send
    End With
    Cells(i, 12) = "Yes"
    
    End If
                 
        i = i + 1
        Loop
    Set olAppt = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
     ThisWorkbook.Save
    Exit Sub
     
Err_Execute:
    MsgBox "An error occurred - Exporting items to Calendar."
     
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of relying on an error happening, why not just check to see if it exists and act accordingly? The `Dir` function can do that, and so can a file system object.

Comment: Do you have an example of doing this? I want to keep it referencing the file structure as it is, so that it will work seamlessly on multiple machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to braX, this was resolved using the below code

```
    Do Until Trim(Cells(i, 1).Value) = ""
     If Trim(Cells(i, 12).Value) = "" Then
    On Error Resume Next
    Set olAppt = CalFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
    arrCal = Cells(i, 6).Value
    Set subFolder = CalFolder.Folders.Add(arrCal)
    Set olAppt = subFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
```

This block of code added into the above code, will take a string from a cell in Excel, and add it to a calendar on Outlook, if that calendar does not exist, then it will create it and then add it.  It will not add an already existing calendar.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your `CalFolder.Folders(arrCal)`, but I'm assuming that returns a string if you are trying to use it with `MkDir`

```
Sub test()
  CreateFolderIfNotExist "C:\Test"
End Sub

Sub CreateFolderIfNotExist(sFolder As String)
  If Dir(sFolder, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MkDir sFolder
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Tbh, the MkDir is from something I found while googling around.  

CalFolder.Folders(arrCal), should be the location of the folder/subfolders in outlook.  It works if the subfolder has already been created in Outlook, and arrCal is defined by a cell in Excel. 

Essentially, I just want to make it so if the subfolder defined by arrCal doesn't exist in Outlook, then it will create it and then run the rest of the script.

Comment: ```Set olAppt = CalFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
    arrCal = Cells(i, 6).Value
    Set subFolder = CalFolder.Folders(arrCal)
    Set olAppt = subFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)```

This is the entire setup for the directory that assigns the calendar to save everything to

Comment: Then you do not want `MkDir` - Read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folders.add

Comment: Figured it out! Added an answer with the details and the code.  If you want to post it yourself, I can give you Answer credit.

Comment: No need to give me credit, you figured it out on your own with just a nudge in the right direction from me. I would still try to find a way to do it without `On Error Resume Next` - There should be a way to check to see if it exists. Maybe this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folders.item

Comment: At any rate, your own answer is better, so you can just vote your own answer as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

`On Error Resume Next` requires care.

An error adding a folder, if it exists, is ignored.

`On Error GoTo 0` limits the scope of the error bypass to one line.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub CreateOutlookAppointments()

    Sheets("PTH").Select
    
    On Error GoTo Err_Execute
    
    ' Set reference to Microsoft Outlook XX.X Object Library
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
    
    Dim CalFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim subFolder As Outlook.Folder
    
    Dim arrCal As String
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' CreateObject initiates the one Outlook instance allowed.
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set CalFolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    
    i = 3
    
    Do Until Trim(Cells(i, 1).Value) = ""
    
        If Trim(Cells(i, 12).Value) = "" Then

            arrCal = Cells(i, 6).Value
            
            On Error Resume Next
            ' ignore error when arrCal folder exists
            Set subFolder = CalFolder.Folders.Add(arrCal)
            ' remove error bypass immediately
            On Error GoTo 0
            
            Set subFolder = CalFolder.Folders(arrCal)
            Set olAppt = subFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
            
            With olAppt
                'Define calendar item properties
                .Start = Cells(i, 5) + TimeValue("9:00:00")
                .End = Cells(i, 5) + TimeValue("17:00:00")
                .Subject = Cells(i, 1) + " " + Cells(i, 2)
                .body = Cells(i, 6) & vbNewLine & Cells(2, 4) & vbNewLine & Cells(i, 4)
                .ReminderSet = False
                .Save
            End With
            
            Cells(i, 12) = "Yes"
    
        End If
                 
        i = i + 1
        
    Loop
    
    Set olAppt = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
        
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    
    Exit Sub
     
Err_Execute:
    MsgBox "An error occurred - Exporting items to Calendar."
     
End Sub
```